# Finding the winning distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

One game consists of choosing a point on a $10$ feet long rope. You pay \$$3$ to play and
earn \$$| 5 - X |$ where $X$ is the chosen number.

$1)$ Find the earnings distribution.
$2)$ If you play twice with $X_1, X_2$ and $X=\max\{X_1,X_2\}$, what would the earnings distribution of $X$ be?

I literally have no idea how to solve this problem, like really nothing.

Comment: Usually, when a problem is presented where the OP (i.e. original poster) is *lost*, there are two possibilities: [1] the problem is from a book or class that the OP is involved in, or [2] this is a somewhat random problem that the OP either made up or saw on the internet.  To receive help, you need to provide the source of the problem + your math background.  See also [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), which discusses the protocol for asking a *good* question on mathSE.

Comment: Who does the choosing?  If you do it, then choose either $0$ or $10$ and get $5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$. We assume $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,10]$. The *profit* $Y$ (I think this is what you mean by 'earnings') distribution is found by first computing the cdf
$$P(Y\leq y)=P(|X-5|-3\leq y)=P(-y+2\leq X\leq y+8)= \\
=\frac{1}{10}\int_{[-y+2,y+8]\cap [0,10]}dx=\frac{y+3}{5}, \ \ \ y \in [-3,2]$$
so the pdf is $\partial_yP(Y\leq y)=1/5$.

$2)$. If we have $X=\max(X_1,X_2)$ then
$$P(X\leq x)=P(\max(X_1,X_2)\leq x)=P(\{X_1\leq x\}\cap\{X_2\leq x\})= \\
=\frac{1}{10^2}\int_{[0,x]}\int_{[0,x]}dx_1dx_2=\frac{x^2}{10^2}$$
so the pdf is  $\partial_xP(X\leq x)=x/50$ over $[0,10]$ and indeed
$$\frac{1}{50}\int_{[0,10]}xdx=\frac{1}{50}\frac{100}{2}=1$$
So the earnings cdf is
$$P(Y \leq y)=P(-y+2\leq X\leq y+8)=\frac{1}{50}\int_{[-y+2,y+8]\cap[0,10]}xdx=\\=\frac{(y+8)^2-(2-y)^2}{10^2}=\frac{60+20y}{10^2}=\frac{y+3}{5}$$
so the pdf is $\partial_yP(Y\leq y)=1/5$.